# How can I mount cabinetry to metal furring strips with shallow depth?

Tags: mounting, hanging, anchor, fastener

I'm trying to mount IKEA Besta cabinets and a 55" tv to my condo wall.  The drywall is 1/2" and is attached to a concrete wall with 1" depth metal drywall furring strips spaced 24" apart.

I was thinking about using toggle bolts or spring toggles through the furring but there isn't enough space for them to open up (concrete wall in the way).

Are there any tricks to get this to work without opening the wall and adding support lumber?  (I'm assuming the toggle bolts would be strong enough to hold the cabinets) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use cement anchors. There are several types. Hammer-set are like a nail--you push them in through the support into the cement, then use a hammer to drive a pin in the center that causes the anchor to expand. They're quick and  easy but not easily removable.

Another type of expanding anchor is referred to by a brand name Red Head. Drill similar holes to the hammer-set, but with this one the sleeve is pushed into the hole and a bolt is tightened, causing the expansion (the bolt holds the support in place). If you want to remove this type of anchor, remove the bolt and the anchor can be pushed into the hole.

These are the 2 types I use the most often and neither requires the wall to be opened. Both are many times stronger than toggle bolts.

Comment: there is still about a 1" void between the drywall and the concrete.  Will these anchors work properly if they are sticking out that 1"? Or should they be flush with the concrete (I'd imagine when fastening the cabinets, it would break the drywall because of the space between the drywall and concrete)

Comment: I usually drill at the furring strips so there is support from the strip.